# Breadwallet: Recovery Passphrase

Tags: mobile, ios

[Breadwallet](http://breadwallet.com) uses a recovery passphrase in case you loose your phone. I read that you can reimport your wallet using a private key only once and after that you have to export it again in order to be able to import it a second time (see [Using Paper Wallets](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1c9xr7/psa_using_paper_wallets_understanding_change/)).

Is the key derivation method breadwallet uses also susceptible to that, or can I use this passphrase multiple times to recover the wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wallet passphrase (Bip39 mnemonic) as many times as you like. You don't have to export it again.

But mind, breadwallet does not follow the bip44 chainpath scheme. Importing the passphrase into a different wallet application would first require to "convert the keypath" with a tool.

But i would recommend to **not** use the same wallet passphrase (bip39 mnemonic) on multiple devices simultaneous! You might reuse addresses and run into a chance of creating double spends.

Comment: So is it BIP39 or BIP32? [This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/breadwallet/comments/6hh84b/how_do_i_generate_private_keys_using_the/dj1l0an/) says it is BIP32.

Comment: It's both AFAIK. BIP39 defines the Mnemonic (the words your have to write down that represents your seed) while BIP32 defines how keys are derived from the master seed.